# Radial Schrödinger equation: from $R_l(r)$ to $u_l(r)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, definition

I am in the 3-dimensional radial Schrödinger equation, in the spherical coordinates, where we try to find the separable solutions

$$\psi(r) = R_l(r) Y_l^m(\theta, \varphi) \equiv \frac{u_l(r)}{r}Y_l^m(\theta, \varphi).$$ ($\theta$ is the colatitude and $\varphi$ the azimuthal angle.)

I've been trying for an hour to get from this line to the next one:

$$\left[-\frac{\hbar}{2m} \left( \frac{1}{r} \frac{d^2}{dr^2} r - \frac{l(l+1)}{r^2} \right) + V(r)\right] R_l(r) Y_l^m(\theta, \varphi) = ER_l(r) Y_l^m(\theta, \varphi)$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow \left[-\frac{\hbar}{2m} \left(  \frac{d^2}{dr^2} - \frac{l(l+1)}{r^2} \right) + V(r)\right] u_l(r) = Eu_l(r)$$
How did the $\frac{1}{r}$ and $r$ dissapear with $u_l(r)$?

Comment: Hint: Check the definition in the first equation.

Comment: Are you sure that the line you are starting from is right? According to Griffiths 2nd edition Eq. (4.35) the second derivative term is different. It should be $$ \frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{d}{dr}\left( r^{2}\frac{dR}{dr}\right) $$

Comment: I just checked in my textbook, the equation is the one I wrote. Maybe they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it seems like you've resolved your particular issue, this might be a good opportunity to think about how operations work more generally, as you will come to see a lot of operator algebra in quantum mechanics.

Taking your first equation and substituting $R(r) \rightarrow u(r)/r$ and dividing by $Y(\theta,\varphi)$, we get
\begin{equation}
 \left[ -\frac{\hbar}{2m} \left( \frac{1}{r} \frac{d^2}{dr^2} r - \frac{l(l+1)}{r^2} \right)
 + V(r) \right]\frac{u(r)}{r} =
 E \frac{u(r)}{r}.
\end{equation}
Someone who is used to regular (scalar) algebra might be tempted to simply cancel the $1/r$ factors multiplying $u(r)$ on both sides. This would be fine if not for a certain term on the left-hand side;
\begin{equation} \tag{1} \label{term}
 -\frac{\hbar}{2m} \left( \frac{1}{r} \frac{d^2}{dr^2} r \right)\frac{u(r)}{r}.
\end{equation}
There are two important reasons why we can't just multiply this term by $r$ to get rid of the $r$ dividing $u(r)$.

1. Operators are applied from the left, by convention.
2. The differential operator $d/dr$ does not *commute* with multiplication by a factor which involves $r$;

\begin{equation}
 \frac{d}{dr}f(r) \neq f(r)\frac{d}{dr}.
\end{equation}
With this in mind, if we multiply (\ref{term}) by $r$ we should do so from the left (you can think of it as applying a multiplication operator), which cancels the $1/r$ factor there (scalar multiplications do, of course, commute). The remaining part then tells us to first multiply $u(r)/r$ by $r$  and then differentiate the result twice with respect to $r$, which is why we get
\begin{equation}
 -\frac{\hbar}{2m}\frac{d^2u}{dr^2}.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

A friend just explained me that actually, turning $R_l(r)$ into $u_l(r)/r$ made a $\frac{1}{r}$ appear everywhere, except in the $\frac{d^2}{dr^2}$ term where the $r R_l(r)$ turns into $u_l(r)$. As there was already a $\frac{1}{r}$ in front of $\frac{d^2}{dr^2}$, all the $\frac{1}{r}$ and $Y_l^m(\theta, \varphi)$ just dissapear.